# query string in php

Tags: php, security

This code have some problem of Security? is a correct way to make a query string ?

I don't usually use this type of code, so my question.

```
 <?php
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    ?>
    <?
    switch($id) {

        case "principal":
            $pagina = "pag.php";
            break;
        case "perfil":
            $pagina = "secure.php";
            break;

        default:
            $pagina = "home.php";
            break;
    }
    ?>

    <?
    if( (isset($pagina)) and (file_exists($pagina)) ) {
        include($pagina);
    } else {
        echo "Page error";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: `require_once` is much better practise instead of `include` and try to use `intval` if it possible (in your ids)

Comment: disagree with `require_once`, it takes a little longer than require and if your app is organized correctly you shouldnt need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your select statement gets big i'd recommend using arrays:

```
// array of pages
$paginas = array(
    'principal' => 'pag.php',
    'perfil' => 'secure.php'
);

$id = (int)$_GET['id'];

if ( isset( $paginas[$id] ) && file_exists($paginas[$id]) ) {
    require( $paginas[$id] );
}
else {
    require('home.php');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only possible problem is that if you're getting ID from the $_REQUEST, someone could change your query by putting ?id=x in the URL string.  It might not matter in your case (tough to say since we don't know the full context of what's going on) but it's a possibility.  You could make it a bit more secure by sending the variable to the page via a $_POST, which is hidden to the user.

Answer (score 1):

An intruder could guess the id from secure.php and access it by entering yourpage.php?id=perfil in his browser...

Comment: if the page is private i will use sessions

Answer (score 0):

You have a handler for every situation involving $id so it should be safe. You also don't need this since $pagina will always be set: `(isset($pagina))`

Answer (score 0):

I'd add some `htmlspecialchars` to that. You'll never know what people could try doing!

If you wanted to be "doubley" sure, then you could always do;

```
filter_var($val, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Comment: Why would you add htmlspecialchars? It makes no sense in the context of what is being done.

Comment: This is true and be getting over zealous with it all. Still, `filter_var` is always good.

Comment: You are familiar with KISS principle? :)

Comment: neither of those are necessary and while they might seem like a good practice they waste CPU time (which doesn't matter for small sites, but if it gets large it could) -- you can't break out or inject code into a switch statement expression.

Comment: In this case, I agree it's not necessary since he covers his bases with his switch statement.